# Is and Brier Score the right approach to evaluate this binomial glm model?

Tags: r, glm

I want to evaluate a calculator that predicts events by calculating an estimated percentage of the probability that the event will occur based on numerous input variables (in practice it's about patients with risk factors and postoperative complications). Unfortunately I have no insight on how the calculator actually works but can only look at input/output values. After entering a number of scenarios I end up with a df like this:

```
risk <- runif(100, 0, 1)
event <- sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE) 
test.df <- data.frame(risk, event)
```

Risk describes the predicted probability and event describes if the complication actually occurred.

Now I want to find out how good the calculator is at predicting complications in my patients.

Would it be suitable to use a binomial glm and evaluate it by using a scaled brier score?

```
library (stats)
library (DescTools)
mod <- glm(event ~ risk, family = binomial, data = test.df)
BrierScore(mod, scaled = TRUE)
```

From my perspective one could also directly calculate a Brier Score and Scaled Brier Score from the df, but I'm unsure if this would be the correct approach.

```
BS <- function(obs, pred) {
          mean((obs - pred)^2)
        }
        
Scaled_BS <- function(obs, pred) {
          1 - (BS(obs, pred) / (mean(obs) * (1 - mean(obs))))
        }
BS(event, risk)
Scaled_BS(event, risk)
```

Please forgive me if this is a completely wrong approach. I'm new to this kind of task and any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Brier score is fine but you can complement with ROC analysis which is designed to test binary outcomes. The key in ROC analysis is returning a value between 0-1. The closest to 1 is, the better the predictions are. And if the value is close to 0.5 then the prediction is random and lack of predictive power. The rule of thumb is that the performance for a model is proper if the AUROC is over 0.7. I have sketched a code for you using `ROCR` package:

```
library(ROCR)
#Data
risk <- runif(100, 0, 1)
event <- sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE) 
test.df <- data.frame(risk, event)
#Model
mod <- glm(event ~ risk, family = binomial, data = test.df)
#Evaluate
test.df$score<-predict(mod,type='response',test.df)
pred<-prediction(test.df$score,test.df$event)
discr=performance(pred,"auc")
#Compute AUROC
AUROC=as.numeric(discr@y.values)
```

The output for `AUROC` is:

```
AUROC
[1] 0.5700522
```

Which is low. Also you can plot the ROC curve, the closest the curve is to left superior corner means that predictions come from a high performance model. In the case of your data:

[image]

Which is the middle of the square and not close to the left superior corner. This measure can help you to determine the performance of your model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift support and the recommendation regarding AUROC. I wanted to use the Brier Score because it was used by other colleagues in context of the same calculator. I guess in the end both approaches should yield a result with similar tendency? Thanks again and have a nice weekend!

Comment: @NR117 Many thanks! Yeah both measures quantify performance but AUROC uses to be more accurate as the AUROC is understood as a probability. The close to 1 better classification. Brier score returns a number that sometimes can be difficult to interpret. Hope that helps you :)